# Count "truthy" values in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, array-filter

Given the following array `$mm`

```
Array
(
    [147] => Array
        (
            [pts_m] => 
            [pts_mreg] => 1
            [pts_cg] => 1
        )    
    [158] => Array
        (
            [pts_m] => 
            [pts_mreg] => 
            [pts_cg] => 0
        )

    [159] => Array
        (
            [pts_m] => 
            [pts_mreg] => 1
            [pts_cg] => 1
        )

)
```

When I run `count(array_filter($mm))` I get `3` as result since it is not recursive.

`count(array_filter($mm), COUNT_RECURSIVE)` also will not do because I actually need to run the `array_filter` recursively, and then count its result.

So my question is: how do I recursively run `array_filter($mm)` in this case? 
My expected result here would be `4`.

Please note that I am not using any callback so I can exclude false, null and empty.

Comment: Are you simply trying to count the array elements that have a value?

Comment: @jrod that's correct, but not 0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should work

```
$count = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {
  return ((int) !is_null($item['pts_m'])
       + ((int) !is_null($item['pts_mreg'])
       + ((int) !is_null($item['pts_cg']);
}, $array);
```

or maybe

```
$count = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {
  return array_sum(array_map('is_int', $item));
}, $array);
```

There are definitely many more possible solutions. If you want to use `array_filter()` (without callback) remember, that it treats `0` as `false` too and therefore it will *remove* any `0`-value from the array.

If you are using PHP in a pre-5.3 version, I would use a `foreach`-loop

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
  $count += ((int) !is_null($item['pts_m'])
          + ((int) !is_null($item['pts_mreg'])
          + ((int) !is_null($item['pts_cg']);
}
```

---

### Update

Regarding the comment below:

> Thx @kc I actually want the method to remove false, 0, empty etc

When this is really only, what you want, the solution is very simple too. 
But now I don't know, how to interpret

> My expected result here would be 5.

Anyway, its short now :)

```
$result = array_map('array_filter', $array);
$count = array_map('count', $result);
$countSum = array_sum($count);
```

The resulting array looks like

```
Array
(
[147] => Array
    (
        [pts_mreg] => 1
        [pts_cg] => 1
    )    
[158] => Array
    (
    )

[159] => Array
    (
        [pts_mreg] => 1
        [pts_cg] => 1
    )

)
```

Comment: Thx @kc I actually want the method to remove false, 0, empty etc

Comment: Your statement "My expected result here would be `5`." is quite misleading then and after remove any `false`-evaluated value `count($array)` will still not return `0`.

Comment: "... still not return `5`". It counts the elements of the array and an array is an element and therefore will get counted as `1` (I just don't wanted this comment to be a silly "want to fix my typo"..)

Answer (score 33):

From the [PHP `array_filter` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#87581):

```
//This function filters an array and remove all null values recursively. 

<?php 
  function array_filter_recursive($input) 
  { 
    foreach ($input as &$value) 
    { 
      if (is_array($value)) 
      { 
        $value = array_filter_recursive($value); 
      } 
    } 

    return array_filter($input); 
  } 
?> 

//Or with callback parameter (not tested) : 

<?php 
  function array_filter_recursive($input, $callback = null) 
  { 
    foreach ($input as &$value) 
    { 
      if (is_array($value)) 
      { 
        $value = array_filter_recursive($value, $callback); 
      } 
    } 

    return array_filter($input, $callback); 
  } 
?>
```

Comment: would this also remove empty and 0?

Comment: @torr - This would work the same way as `array_filter` normally does. If you look in the function, it calls `array_filter` unless it's the current value is an array at which point it calls the `array_filter_recursive` function.

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes: `array_filter_recursive` with callback does not work as expected, it gives array to string conversion errors while recursion..

Comment: Does not work with callback provided. See my answer for a working function

Comment: If I do not pass a callback (callback is null), the result is also null :/ Can't figure out why

Answer (score 8):

**A better alternative**

One implementation that always worked for me is this one:

```
function filter_me(&$array) {
    foreach ( $array as $key => $item ) {
        is_array ( $item ) && $array [$key] = filter_me ( $item );
        if (empty ( $array [$key] ))
            unset ( $array [$key] );
    }
    return $array;
}
```

I notice that someone had created a similar function except that this one presents, in my opinion, few advantages:

1. you pass an array as reference (not its copy) and thus the algorithm is memory-friendly
2. no additional calls to array_filter which in reality involves:

   - the use of stack, ie. additional memory
   - some other operations, ie. CPU cycles

**Benchmarks**

1. A 64MB array

   - *filter_me* function finished in 0.8s AND the PHP allocated memory before starting the function was 65MB, when function returned it was 39.35MB !!!
   - *array_filter_recursive* function recommended above by Francois Deschenes had no chance; after 1s PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
2. A 36MB array

   - *filter_me* function finished in 0.4s AND the PHP allocated memory before starting the function was 36.8MB, when function returned it was 15MB !!!
   - *array_filter_recursive* function succeeded this time in 0.6s and memory before/after was quite the same

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This function effectively applies filter_recursive with a provided callback

```
class Arr {

    public static function filter_recursive($array, $callback = NULL)
    {
        foreach ($array as $index => $value)
        {
            if (is_array($value))
            {
                $array[$index] = Arr::filter_recursive($value, $callback);
            }
            else
            {
                $array[$index] = call_user_func($callback, $value);
            }

            if ( ! $array[$index])
            {
                unset($array[$index]);
            }
        }

        return $array;
    }

}
```

And you'd use it this way:

```
Arr::filter_recursive($my_array, $my_callback);
```

This might help someone

Comment: It may help so it's good to know. Anyway, the question was related to how to filter out those 'empty' records and my answer focused to provide a better alternative with respect to that problem. But I agree that your version of recursive filter has a broader usage.

Comment: Isn't array_filter supposed to preserve the original value if callback returns `true`? In this case you are slamming the original value to `true`

Comment: destroys the input array

Answer (score 0):

I needed an array filter recursive function that would walk through all nodes (including arrays, so that we have the possibility to discard entire arrays), and so I came up with this:

```php
    public static function filterRecursive(array $array, callable $callback): array
    {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            $res = call_user_func($callback, $v);
            if (false === $res) {
                unset($array[$k]);
            } else {
                if (is_array($v)) {
                    $array[$k] = self::filterRecursive($v, $callback);
                }
            }
        }

        return $array;
    }
```

See more examples here: https://github.com/lingtalfi/Bat/blob/master/ArrayTool.md#filterrecursive

Comment: this mutates the input array

Answer (score 0):

This should work for callback and mode support along with an optional support for depth.

```
function array_filter_recursive(array $array, callable $callback = null, int $mode = 0, int $depth = -1): array
{
    foreach ($array as & $value) {
        if ($depth != 0 && is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value, $callback, $mode, $depth - 1);
        }
    }

    if ($callback) {
        return array_filter($array, $callback, $mode);
    }

    return array_filter($array);
}
```

Calling the function with `$depth = 0` for nested arrays, will yield the same result as `array_filter`.

Answer (score 0):

This strike me as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).

1. Recursion is not necessary because the array has a consistent depth of 2 levels.
2. It is not necessary to generate an array of filtered elements so that you can traverse the filtered data to count it. Just traverse once and add 1 to the count variable whenever a truthy value is encountered.

The following snippet calls no functions (only language constructs -- `foreach()`) and therefore will be highly efficient.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nhcv9))

```
$truthyCount = 0;
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $v) {
        $truthyCount += (bool) $v;
    }
}
var_export($truthyCount);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$mm = array
(
    147 => array
        (
            "pts_m" => "",
            "pts_mreg" => 1,
            "pts_cg" => 1
        ) ,
    158 => array
        (
            "pts_m" => null ,
            "pts_mreg" => null,
            "pts_cg" => 0
        ),

    159 => array
        (
            "pts_m" => "",
            "pts_mreg" => 1,
            "pts_cg" => 1
        )

);

$count = 0;
foreach ($mm as $m) {
    foreach ($m as $value) {
        if($value !== false && $value !== "" && $value !== null) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: Good idea - in that case array_filter could be used instead of the conditionals and $count++, no?