# Search a multidimensional array by key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, key

I have a question about filtering a multidimensional array in PHP.
What i would like to achieve is to pull a specific array element (the value of mediacontent) from an existing array.
This is what i got so far:

**Existing multidimensional array:**

```
$multidimensional_array = array(
    'entry' => array(
        0 => array(
            'width' => array(
                '$t' => '1536'
            ),
            'height' => array(
                '$t' => '2048'
            ),
            'id' => array(
                '$t' => '878974'
            ),
            'mediagroup' => array(
                'mediacontent' => array(
                    'url' => 'http://website/urltotheobject.png',
                    'width' => 384,
                    'medium' => 'image',
                    'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                    'height' => 512
                )
            )
        ),
        1 => array(
            'width' => array(
                    '$t' => '5486'
            ),
            'height' => array(
                    '$t' => '1144'
            ),
            'id' => array(
                '$t' => '485435'
            ),
            'mediagroup' => array(
                'mediacontent' => array(
                    'url' => 'http://website/urltotheobject.png',
                    'width' => 512,
                    'medium' => 'image',
                    'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                    'height' => 384
                )
            )   
        )
    )
);
```

**A (not properly working) function to filter the array**

```
function filterResponseByKey($keyToFilter,$array){

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
    {
        if($key == $keyToFilter)
        {
            return $value;
        }
        elseif(is_array($value))
        {
            $result = filterResponseByKey($keyToFilter, $value);

            if($result != false)
            {
                return $result;             
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm fairly new to PHP and hope you guys could point me in the right direction and tell me what i am doing wrong here.

I did research on the following (alternate)websites but i couldn't find an answer fitting my needs.

[understanding recursion](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-recursion/) , [PHP filter_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Do not need recurion, just simple loop through. So you want to clear those, where, for example `mediacontent` width is bigger then a specific value?

Comment: True, don't use recursion and if you just want a few data from the original array, just build a new one and return with that.

Comment: I would actually use objects and a class approach but if you really want recursion check my answer

Comment: This question is unclear because it doesn't include a [mcve]. We don't know if you want the first found match or all found matches.  We don't know if recursion is actually necessary.  This page is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case I would reccomend you to have an array of objects, as elements 0 and 1 are similar, and have mediacontent as a internal variable.

If your really want to do it you can get an array of mediacontent only by using a map

```
 array_map($multidimensional_array['entry'],function($obj){
     return $obj['mediagroup']['mediacontent'];
 });
```

If what you want is something more dynamic and recursive

```
 function recursive_filter_by_key($keyname,$list){
    $result=[];
    foreach($list as $key=>$obj){
         if($key==$keyname) 
            array_push($result,$obj);

         else if(gettype($obj)=='array')//not necesary to check if its equal to the $key as this wouldn't run if it was
                 $result = array_merge($result,recursive_filter_by_key($obj));
    }
    return $result;

 }
```

This function can return complete arrays within its results array as long as they are the value of the key you are searching

I would like you to comment though as I think I haven't understood your question very much.

Also there is another similar post in the site in case you haven't crossed it
[How to run array_filter recursively in a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795621/how-to-run-array-filter-recursively-in-a-php-array)

Answer (score 1):

The most practical solution for this [uses iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveArrayIterator($multidimensional_array),
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
foreach($iter as $key => $value) {
  if(ctype_alpha($key) && $key == 'mediacontent') {
    echo "Media Content: ".print_r($value, true)."\n";
  }
}
```

This will output:

```
Media Content: Array
(
    [url] => http://website/urltotheobject.png
    [width] => 384
    [medium] => image
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [height] => 512
)

Media Content: Array
(
    [url] => http://website/urltotheobject.png
    [width] => 512
    [medium] => image
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [height] => 384
)
```

Iterators are a much underappreciated feature of PHP, although they do have a tricky syntax at times, and in this case you're interested in nodes instead of leaves, requiring the extra mode parameter. The recursive iterators however do simplify a lot of recursive operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this way also for just mediacontent....

```
$multidimensional_array = array(
        'entry' => array(
            0 => array(
                'width' => array(
                    '$t' => '1536'
                ),
                'height' => array(
                    '$t' => '2048'
                ),
                'id' => array(
                    '$t' => '878974'
                ),
                'mediagroup' => array(
                    'mediacontent' => array(
                        'url' => 'http://website/urltotheobject.png',
                        'width' => 384,
                        'medium' => 'image',
                        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                        'height' => 512
                    )
                )
            ),
            1 => array(
                'width' => array(
                    '$t' => '5486'
                ),
                'height' => array(
                    '$t' => '1144'
                ),
                'id' => array(
                    '$t' => '485435'
                ),
                'mediagroup' => array(
                    'mediacontent' => array(
                        'url' => 'http://website/urltotheobject.png',
                        'width' => 512,
                        'medium' => 'image',
                        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                        'height' => 384
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    function getMediaContent($item){
        return $item['mediagroup']['mediacontent'];
    }
    $mediacontent = array_map('getMediaContent', $multidimensional_array['entry']);
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($mediacontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterResponseByKey($keyToFilter,$array){

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
    {
        if($key === $keyToFilter)
        {
            return $value;
        }
        elseif(is_array($value))
        {
            $result = filterResponseByKey($keyToFilter, $value);

            if($result != false)
            {
                return $result;             
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now working!

edit: to explain:

Using "==" checks to find if equal regardless of type, so when it encounters a interger, it will cast both values to check as a interger int('anystring')  results in 0 , so the key 0 = string 'mediacontent'