# How to remove (not unset) key-value pairs from an associative array which contains null value in them in an optimum and efficient way?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've an associative array titled `$post_data` as follows. The actual array is very large for your reference I'm just putting below two elements of it :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [feed_id] => 1331
            [app_id] => 0
            [privacy] => 0
            [privacy_comment] => 0
            [type_id] => user_status
            [user_id] => 244
            [parent_user_id] => 0
            [item_id] => 140
            [time_stamp] => 1424256681
            [feed_reference] => 0
            [parent_feed_id] => 0
            [parent_module_id] => 
            [time_update] => 1424256681
            [app_title] => 
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_server_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-244
            [full_name] => Campusknot .
            [gender] => 0
            [user_image] => 2015/02/0f34dbb95ce18b17611220b78c87f9a6%s.png
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 7
            [language_id] => 
            [feed_time_stamp] => 1424256681
            [can_post_comment] => 1
            [feed_status] => feed with smily <img src="http://34.144.40.142/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" />
            [feed_title] => 
            [feed_link] => http://34.144.40.142/profile-244/status-id_140/
            [total_comment] => 0
            [feed_total_like] => 0
            [feed_is_liked] => 
            [feed_icon] => http://34.144.40.142/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/misc/application_add.png
            [enable_like] => 1
            [comment_type_id] => user_status
            [like_type_id] => user_status
            [likes] => Array
                (
                )

            [marks] => Array
                (
                )

            [bShowEnterCommentBlock] => 
            [feed_month_year] => 02_2015
            [feed_like_phrase] => 
            [profile_image] => http://34.144.40.142/file/pic/user/2015/02/0f34dbb95ce18b17611220b78c87f9a6_50_square.png
            [feed_image] => 
            [user_group_name] => faculty
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [feed_id] => 1310
            [app_id] => 0
            [privacy] => 0
            [privacy_comment] => 0
            [type_id] => photo
            [user_id] => 244
            [parent_user_id] => 0
            [item_id] => 606
            [time_stamp] => 1424235811
            [feed_reference] => 0
            [parent_feed_id] => 0
            [parent_module_id] => 
            [time_update] => 1424235811
            [app_title] => 
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_server_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-244
            [full_name] => Campusknot .
            [gender] => 0
            [user_image] => 2015/02/0f34dbb95ce18b17611220b78c87f9a6%s.png
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 7
            [language_id] => 
            [feed_time_stamp] => 1424235811
            [can_post_comment] => 1
            [feed_title] => 
            [feed_image] => http://34.144.40.142/file/pic/photo/2015/02/02ff1a23db112db834b8f41748242bcb_240.png
            [feed_status] => new_image
            [feed_link] => http://34.144.40.142/photo/606/after_login/userid_244/
            [total_comment] => 0
            [feed_total_like] => 1
            [feed_is_liked] => 910
            [feed_icon] => http://34.144.40.142/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/module/photo.png
            [enable_like] => 1
            [comment_type_id] => photo
            [like_type_id] => photo
            [custom_css] =>  js_photo_item_606  photo_holder_image
            [custom_rel] => 606
            [custom_js] => 
            [no_target_blank] => 1
            [custom_data_cache] => Array
                (
                    [parent_user_id] => 0
                    [parent_profile_page_id] => 
                    [user_parent_server_id] => 
                    [parent_user_name] => 
                    [parent_full_name] => 
                    [parent_gender] => 
                    [parent_user_image] => 
                    [parent_is_invisible] => 
                    [parent_user_group_id] => 
                    [parent_language_id] => 
                    [photo_id] => 606
                    [album_id] => 
                    [view_id] => 0
                    [module_id] => 
                    [group_id] => 0
                    [type_id] => 1
                    [privacy] => 0
                    [privacy_comment] => 0
                    [title] => after_login
                    [user_id] => 244
                    [destination] => 2015/02/02ff1a23db112db834b8f41748242bcb%s.png
                    [server_id] => 0
                    [mature] => 0
                    [allow_comment] => 0
                    [allow_rate] => 0
                    [time_stamp] => 1424235811
                    [total_view] => 0
                    [total_comment] => 0
                    [total_download] => 0
                    [total_rating] => 0.00
                    [total_vote] => 0
                    [total_battle] => 0
                    [total_like] => 1
                    [total_dislike] => 0
                    [is_featured] => 0
                    [is_cover] => 0
                    [allow_download] => 0
                    [is_sponsor] => 0
                    [ordering] => 0
                    [is_profile_photo] => 0
                    [is_liked] => 910
                    [description] => new_image
                    [extra_photo_id] => 
                    [name] => 
                )

            [feed_info] => posted a photo
            [likes] => Array
                (
                    [244] => Array
                        (
                            [like_id] => 910
                            [type_id] => photo
                            [item_id] => 606
                            [user_id] => 244
                            [time_stamp] => 1424247486
                            [profile_page_id] => 0
                            [user_server_id] => 0
                            [user_name] => profile-244
                            [full_name] => Campusknot .
                            [gender] => 0
                            [user_image] => 2015/02/0f34dbb95ce18b17611220b78c87f9a6%s.png
                            [is_invisible] => 0
                            [user_group_id] => 7
                            [language_id] => 
                            [action_time_stamp] => 
                        )

                )

            [marks] => Array
                (
                )

            [bShowEnterCommentBlock] => 1
            [feed_month_year] => 02_2015
            [feed_like_phrase] => You&nbsp;like this.
            [profile_image] => http://34.144.40.142/file/pic/user/2015/02/0f34dbb95ce18b17611220b78c87f9a6_50_square.png
            [user_group_name] => faculty
        )
)
```

The actual array is quite large. I want an efficient and optimum way which removes the key-value pairs from the above array that contains null (i.e. nothing) (**including the inner arrays wherever present**).

I don't want to unset the null values from the respective keys containing null value, I want to delete that respective pair of key-value from the array `$post_data` and in result I should get the cleaned up `$post_data` array.

Basically, I don't want to traverse through the whole associative array (i.e. iterating through all the inner arrays present and check each key-value pair in it for null value check). It will be a more complicated and time-consuming. I want to get this thing done using built-in PHP array function like `array_filter()` or something else. I tried using `array_filter()` but it didn't work out for me. I think I'm making some mistake in using this function.

I tried following code but it didn't worked out.

```
    foreach($post_data as $key=>$value) {

    array_filter($value);
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $k=>$v)
        array_filter($v);

      if(is_array($v)){
        foreach($v as $ke=>$va)
          array_filter($va);
      }
    }            
  }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php may be helpful.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley:If you look at the code I tried(present at the end of question description) I've used the same function array_filter() for all the internal array levels but couldn't remove the key-value pairs containing empty values. That's why asking for help.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley:Basically I don't want to traverse through the whole associative array(i.e. iterating through all the inner arrays present and check each key-value pair in it for null value check). It will be a more complicated and time-consuming. I want to get this thing done using built-in PHP array function like array_filter() or something else. I tried using array_filter() but it didn't work out for me. I think I'm making some mistake in using this function. If someone could guide me in achieving this output array it would be really helpful to me. Thanks for showing interest in my issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run array\_filter recursively in a PHP array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795621/how-to-run-array-filter-recursively-in-a-php-array)

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley:In the question you referred there is only one level of inner array. In my case there are many such levels of inner array. If you could post a proper answer considering my array $post_data to achieve the final desired array it would be really great for me as well as other community members who face the same kind of issue. Thanks once again.

Comment: @I tried using code array_map('array_filter', $post_data) but it is removing null keys from first inner array only not from other levels of inner array. That's why I'm requesting you to write a proper answer to the question.

Comment: @PHPLover did you try recursively?

Comment: Can an homemade php module be considered ? It will be the more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

As per your request, here is a function that uses no loops to recursively remove `null` array indexes utilizing [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

### The Function:

```
function array_filter_null_recursive( $array ) {
    //Filter the elements with a custom callback function, passing value as reference.
    return array_filter( $array, function( &$value ) {
        //If this element is an array, recursivly filter and modify the array.
        if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
            $value = array_filter_null_recursive( $value );
            return true;
        }
        //Otherwise, check if null.
        return ! is_null( $value );
    } );
}
```

### Example Usage:

```
$array = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => null,
    'c' => array(
        'a' => null,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => array(
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => null,
        )
    ),
    'd' => null,
    'e' => 5,
);
print_r( array_filter_null_recursive( $array ) );
```

### Example Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => Array
        (
            [b] => 2
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 1
                )

        )

    [e] => 5
)
```

---

However, if speed is you main concern, using a loop with references might actually be a better option. This function averaged slightly faster execution time in my short testing with 100000 calls per test.

### Loop-based function:

```
function array_filter_null_recursive( $array ) {
    foreach ( $array as $k=>&$v ) {
        if ( is_null( $v ) ) {
            unset( $array[$k] );
        }
        elseif ( is_array( $v ) ) {
            $v = array_filter_null_recursive( $v );
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: awesome, the only solution to my problem! But is it advised to do this or not? in terms of performance (and if you take into account that this array will be looped over to display its content in the view)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'a' => 'a',
    'b' => null,
    'c' => array(
        'a' => null,
        'b' => 'b',
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'a' => null
    )
);

$result = array_walk_recursive_delete($array);

echo"<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo"<pre>";

function array_walk_recursive_delete(array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_walk_recursive_delete($value);
        }
        if ($value == null) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/0ddOM)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple recursive version of array_filter:

```
 function mfilter($obj) {
    if (!is_array($obj)) return $obj;
    return array_map("mfilter", array_filter($obj));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the gist is in the responses above, but since I spent a couple hours benchmarking the different functions and iterators, might as well throw in what performed fastest for my install (5.6.something):

```
<?php
$testData = array(
    'a' => "",
    'b' => 0,
    'c' => "0",
    'd' => 1,
    'e' => "1",
    'f' => 0.12,
    'g' => "0.12",
    'h' => array(),
    'i' => array(
        array()
    ),
    'j' => array(
        array(
            array()
        )
    ),
    'k' => array(
        'k1' => array(
            'k1a' => array(),
        )
    ),
    'l' => array(
        'l1' => array(),
        'l2' => 2,
        'l3' => array(
            'l3a' => 1,
            'l3b' => array()
        )
    ),
    array(),
    "testString"
);

$result = array_filter($testData, $f = function(&$v) use (&$f) {
    if (is_array($v) && $v) {
        $v = array_filter($v, $f);
    }
    return (is_array($v) && $v) || (!is_array($v) && trim($v) !== "");
});

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep empty strings, zero numbers and so on, but remove only values which are null's exactly use the following code with callback function, otherwise just remove a callback parameter.

```
$array = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => null,
    'c' => array(
        'a' => null,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => array(
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => null,
        ),
        'd' => '',
        'e' => 0
    ),
    'd' => null,
    'e' => 5,
);

function array_filter_recursive($input, $callback)
{
    foreach ($input as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value, $callback);
        }
    }

    return array_filter($input, $callback);
}

print_r(array_filter_recursive(
    $array,
    function ($val) {
        return !is_null($val);
    }
));
```

Comment: Why don't you just nest them and take out the third iteration call in your print_r()? I'm not trying to be a jerk, I just want to make sure I'm not missing something  ( see my answer above for an example of what I'm talking about -- the only part you'd need to change is the final return statement that does the type checking of that recursion ).

Comment: @PatrickWebster Of course it is possible, that's just a more flexible example, because it's not actually clear what TS wants to filter, exact null values or the values equal to false in PHP.