# array_filter() just filtering the root nodes

Tags: php

I have this multidimensional array:

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Ropa
    [slug] => ropa
    [lft] => 1
    [lvl] => 0
    [rgt] => 2
    [__children] =>       Array ( )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [id] => 3
    [name] => Calzado
    [slug] => calzado
    [lft] => 1
    [lvl] => 0
    [rgt] => 8
    [__children] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [id] => 10
            [name] => Zapatos y botas
            [slug] => zapatos-y-botas
            [lft] => 2
            [lvl] => 1
            [rgt] => 3
            [__children] =>       Array ( )
            )
        [1] => Array (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => Zapatillas
            [slug] => zapatillas
            [lft] => 4
            [lvl] => 1
            [rgt] => 7
            [__children] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 14
                    [name] => Zapatillas rojas
                    [slug] => zapatillas-rojas
                    [lft] => 5
                    [lvl] => 2
                    [rgt] => 6
                    [__children] =>       Array ( )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 13
    [name] => Accesorios
    [slug] => accesorios
    [lft] => 1
    [lvl] => 0
    [rgt] => 2
    [__children] =>       Array ( )
    )
```

I can filter the first level nodes of the array using this:

```
    $foobar = array_filter($navbar, function($value) {
          return $value['slug'] == 'accesorios' || $value['slug'] == 'ropa';           
    });
```

so I get this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'Ropa' (length=4)
      'slug' => string 'ropa' (length=4)
      'lft' => int 1
      'lvl' => int 0
      'rgt' => int 2
      '__children' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  2 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => int 13
      'name' => string 'Accesorios' (length=10)
      'slug' => string 'accesorios' (length=10)
      'lft' => int 1
      'lvl' => int 0
      'rgt' => int 2
      '__children' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

But when I try to filter the second or third level nodes using this for example:

```
    $foobar = array_filter($navbar, function($value) {
          return $value['slug'] == 'zapatillas';           
    });
```

I get empty results.. So how can I filter in that array the second or third?

Comment: `array_filter` is not recursive. If you need recursive filtering, you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: And what exactly is the expected result? You want to keep all nodes which have children which match your condition, I assume…?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return full array containing the value, you may use the following:

```
$foobar = array_filter($navbar, function($value) {
     //return true if child slug key contains zapatillas as a value
     return in_array('zapatillas', array_column($value['__children'], 'slug'));
});
```

Comment: What about filtering children of children…?

Answer (score -1):

May be this helps and is related to your problem. As I understood, it's the recursion that is missing for you right?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795671/2660253

Answer (score -2):

```
$foobar = array_filter($navbar, function($value) { foreach($value as $val) {
return $val['slug'] == 'zapatillas'; }
});
```

Comment: Please, always give some explanation and not only the plain code