# Can't remove empty keys from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to delete array elements from an array using array_filter function. It's working fine but there is always ONE element that is not removed.

The array is constructed with array_combine using one simple array and other built with array_chunk.

Here is my code:

```
$arr_a = array("AAA","","CCC","");

$arr_b = array("a1","b1","a2","b2","a3","b3","a4","b4");

$arr_c = array_chunk($arr_b,2);

$c = array_combine($arr_a,$arr_c);

$limpn_url = array_filter($c);
```

If I'd get an error I would not bother to post here a question. But there is no error returning.

When making `print_r($limpn_url);` 
the output is:
`Array ( [AAA] => Array ( [0] => a1 [1] => b1 ) [] => Array ( [0] => a4 [1] => b4 ) [CCC] => Array ( [0] => a3 [1] => b3 ) )`

*note the `[] => Array ( [0] => a4 [1] => b4 )`  That shouldn't be there. Other empty elements were deleted correctly...

Comment: may I know the values of `$arrnmetacheckboxes` and `$canturls`?

Comment: wait..  I edit and complete the code.

Comment: I'm quite sure array_filter is not recursive. You need to walk the array and array_filter each subarray.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run array\_filter recursively in a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795621/how-to-run-array-filter-recursively-in-a-php-array) and specially look at answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795671/5159168

Comment: I believe when David asked for the array he wanted a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve meaning a complete array that we can use to run the code ourselfs. We can't run the code you have posted.

Comment: I replaced arrays with visible values now..  And Having same problem...

Comment: `array_filter()` without a function argument removes values that are equal to `false`, not the keys. You can't have the same key twice, so the last key overwrites the first setting of that key. Rethink your logic.

Comment: So it's empty keys you want to remove? Not empty arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some array functions to remove keys that is empty.

```
$arr_a = array("AAA","","CCC","");

$arr_b = array("a1","b1","a2","b2","a3","b3","a4","b4");

$arr_c = array_chunk($arr_b,2);

$c = array_combine($arr_a,$arr_c);

$limp= array_filter($c);

$filteredkeys = array_filter(array_keys($limp)); // here i remove the "" key

$filtered = array_intersect_key($limp, array_flip($filteredkeys)); // since $filterdkeys is values i need to flip it and intersect with $limp
var_dump($filtered);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  ["AAA"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a1"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "b1"
  }
  ["CCC"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a3"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "b3"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/miNeW

Comment: @SebasRossi feel free to accept the answer if it worked as you expected

Comment: Sorry I am new in this..  
How I do that ?

Comment: No problem. You click on the tick mark left of the answer you find the best. You can read the stack overflow tour and it will show you some basics of how stack overflow works. http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour