# Removing empty JSON parameters

Tags: php, json

I have set a list of variables and their values as such:

```
$exp = "1642873358";
$country_code = "LO";
$item_description = "An item";
$language_code = "";
$price_amount = "5.99";
$price_currency = "EUR";
$urls_authorisation_callback = "https://www.example.com/";
$urls_redirect = "https://www.example.com/";
$urls_unsubscription_redirect = "";
$subscription_duration = "";
$subscription_unit = "";
$subscription_cycles = "";
$subscription_price_amount = "";
$subscription_price_currency = "";
$msisdn = "55555555";
$msisdn_edit_disabled = "";
```

These variable values should be editable can be left empty if preferred so as seen in the example. I do not want to remove the variable.

Then I created an array which is later encoded to JSON:

```
$token = array(
    'exp' => "$exp" ,
    'country_code' => "$country_code",
    'item_description' => "$item_description",
    'language_code' => "$language_code",
    'price' => array(
        'amount' => "$price_amount",
        'currency' => "$price_currency" 
    ),
    'urls' => array(
        'authorisation_callback' => "$urls_authorisation_callback",
        'redirect' => "$urls_redirect",
        'unsubscription_redirect' => "$urls_unsubscription_redirect"
    ),
    'subscription' => array(
        'duration' => "$subscription_duration",
        'unit' => "$subscription_unit" ,
        'cycles' => "$subscription_cycles" ,
        'price' => array(
            'amount' => "$subscription_price_amount",
            'currency' => "$subscription_price_currency"
        )
    ),
    'msisdn' => "$msisdn",
    'msisdn_edit_disabled' => "$msisdn_edit_disabled"
);
```

When I eventually echo JSON text:

```
echo json_encode($token, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "\n";
```

I get the following:

```
{
    "exp": "1642873358",
    "country_code": "LO",
    "item_description": "An item",
    "language_code": "",
    "price": {
        "amount": "5.99",
        "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "urls": {
        "authorisation_callback": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/",
        "redirect": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/",
        "unsubscription_redirect": ""
    },
    "subscription": {
        "duration": "",
        "unit": "",
        "cycles": "",
        "price": {
            "amount": "",
            "currency": ""
        }
    },
    "msisdn": "55555555",
    "msisdn_edit_disabled": ""
}
```

What are my options if I would like to remove the parameters where I have not specified the value? In a way that does not mess up the required JSON structure. Desired result in the given example would be:

```
{
    "exp": "1642873358",
    "country_code": "LO",
    "item_description": "An item",
    "price": {
        "amount": "5.99",
        "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "urls": {
        "authorisation_callback": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/",
        "redirect": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/"
    },
    "msisdn": "55555555"
}
```

Comment: Check that the value is not empty before creating it..

Comment: You shouldn't manually change the json. You should either only add the parameters that has values to begin with, or iterate through the array and remove all empty parameters before you json encode it.

Comment: You don't need to create your array entries as strings, e.g. `'amount' => "$price_amount"` - you can just write `'amount' => $price_amount`. This could also allow you to display numbers as actual numbers in the JSON rather than string.

Comment: In the duplicate, the answer that defines the function `array_filter_recursive()` should do what your after.  This should be run on the array before encoding to JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to and array. using json_decode

then remove empty values using recursive function below. then encode to json again.

```
function array_remove_empty($haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $haystack[$key] = array_remove_empty($haystack[$key]);
        }

        if (empty($haystack[$key])) {
            unset($haystack[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $haystack;
}

$token = array_remove_empty($token);
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29612139/283078, which suggests that this is generally faster than a recursive `array_filter`.