# Php Array_filter to unset key values from array of arrays

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to unset array elements from my nested array of arrays.

I want to perform recursive array filter and i am not sure about how to do that efficiently.

Below is the original array.

```
[
  [a] => 3
  [b] => 0
  [c] => [
    [
      [1] => aa
      [2] => 1
      [3] => [
                [
                  [a1] => 6
                  [a2] => 5781
                  [a3] =>
                      [
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 19550
                        [3] => 5781
                      ]
                ]
                [
                  [a1] => 1
                  [a2] => 5781
                  [a3] =>[
                          [1] => 0
                          [2] => 19550
                          [3] => 5781
                      ]
                ]
              ]
    ]
    [
      [1] => aa
      [2] => 1
      [3] => [
                [
                  [a1] => 6
                  [a2] => 5781
                  [a3] =>
                      [
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 19550
                        [3] => 5781
                      ]
                ]
                [
                  [a1] => 1
                  [a2] => 5781
                  [a3] =>[
                          [1] => 0
                          [2] => 19550
                          [3] => 5781
                      ]
                ]
              ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Expected array

```
[
  [a] => 3
  [c] => [
    [
      [1] => aa
      [3] => [
                [
                  [a1] => 6
                  [a3] =>
                      [
                        [2] => 19550
                        [3] => 5781
                      ]
                ]
                [
                  [a1] => 1
                  [a3] =>[
                          [2] => 19550
                          [3] => 5781
                      ]
                ]
              ]
    ]
    [
      [1] => aa
      [3] => [
                [
                  [a1] => 6
                  [a3] =>
                      [
                        [2] => 19550
                        [3] => 5781
                      ]
                ]
                [
                  [a1] => 1
                  [a3] =>[
                          [2] => 19550
                          [3] => 5781
                      ]
                ]
              ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

As you can see in my expected array from every nested arrays some key value pairs have been removed.
I need to filter the array based on key name.
That is my key names are fixed and that needs to be removed from every children arrays inside.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run array\_filter recursively in a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795621/how-to-run-array-filter-recursively-in-a-php-array)

Comment: Curious, why don't you want to use a `foreach`?

Comment: Already checked that link but i am not clear with that as i need it over array inside array and also want over the innermost array.@Script47

Comment: So should i use nested foreach's????

Comment: or a recursive function?

Comment: Ok i will need to learn more about recursive functions than to make this work.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering the same... recursion I get but why force it into filter/map? Could be done easily using recursion and a simple for/next loop which would be extremely efficient and simpler to follow>

Comment: Ok thankyou so much @JcNolan. Let me try through that recursion approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a recursive foreach based solution to your code working off the data set you provided.

```
    $sourceArray = array("a" => 3, "b" => 0, "c" => array("1" => "aa", "2" => 1, "3" => array("a1" => 6, "a2" => 5781, "a3" => array("1" => 0, "2" => 19550, "3" => 5781)), array( "a1" => 1, "a2" => 5781, "a3" =>array("1" => 0, "2" => 19550, "3" => 5781 ))), array( "1" => "aa", "2" => 1, "3" => array( array( "a1" => 6, "a2" => 5781, "a3" => array( "1" => 0, "2" => 19550,"3" => 5781))), array( "a1" => 1, "a2" => 5781, "a3" =>array(  "1" => 0, "2" => 19550, "3" => 5781))));

    print_r($sourceArray,1);

    function removeKeys($keys, $sourceData) {

        foreach ($sourceData as $key=>$val) {

            if (in_array($key, $keys, true)) {
                unset($sourceData[$key]);
            } else if (is_array($val)) {
                $sourceData[$key] = removeKeys($keys, $sourceData[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $sourceData;
    }

    $keysToRemove = array("b","2","a2");

    $newArray = removeKeys($keysToRemove, $sourceArray);

    print_r($newArray);
```

Simple to implement though getting your data in was a bit of a challenge.  I did notice a "bug" in this example in that if the key is "0" in the original array it still gets deleted even if it's not in the $keys array.

But I'm assuming that this example is sufficient to answer your question and that my stated edge case will not occur (ie, "0" is not a key value in your array.)  If you do use "0" as a key you can add additional logic to trap that case but it would slow the function down a bit so I'll leave that choice up to you.

(Note, the bug referred to above is fixed now and in the code... see notes below for solution from original poster)

Comment: Your ans helped a lot.Just a update about the bug you already told that in_array function matches 0 also even though it is not present.So this can be fixed by using in_array in strict mode as (in_array($key, $keys,true)). Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Nice! Great catch on the "strict" parameter.  Glad I could help!