# What is the default value for callback argument of array_filter function

Tags: php, arrays

What is the default value for `callback` argument of [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function?

Let imagine we have array:

```
$input = [
    "Required field" => true
    "Please, enter a number" => false
];
```

Normally, I use `array_filter` without explicitly setting `callback` parameter, as `array_filter( $input)` and this function will return the following array:

```
$input = [
    "Required field" => true
];
```

But now I need to exactly set `callback` argument. So when I'm sending `null` as callback this functions return `null` and "non empty" value ("Required field" => true) is ignored, what would I not like.

Of course, I can call the function with own callback function like:

```
array_filter( $input, fn($item) => !empty($item) )
```

But I was hoping for more elegant way

Comment: Could you provide the input and desired output that you need for this case where simply calling `array_filter` without a callback is not sufficient for you?

Comment: Concerning your opening question, it is described in the docs you have linked yourself: `If no callback is supplied, all empty entries of array will be removed. See empty() for how PHP defines empty in this case.`

Comment: I just want to filter array from empty values with explicitly setting `callback` argument, but in more elegant way rather than setting own callback function.

Comment: The most elegant way really is *not* setting a callback. Why would you pass a callback that does exactly the same thing as the default?

Comment: I want to make `array_filter_recursive` function. Like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795671/7265862. As you see, in the second function, there is `$callback` argument, which later will be passed to `array_filter` function. I don't want to make if else statement to check for null `$callback` argument. That's why I was asking community for elegant solution

Comment: And I don't want to create two function with the exactly the same purpose as in that post, considering that there is no function overloading in php

Comment: So now, after a discussion, we come to your *real* question. So simply use the first version from that answer (without the callback).

Comment: You so simple :) I'm telling that I don't want to use two different function with exactly the same purpose, assuming that this function will be used for different situations.

Comment: I still fail to see what you're actually trying to do. Edit your question, give sample input and desired output. This way I have to guess what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source code of array_filter contains a second parameter, it is checked whether it is a real callable function. A string can also be passed. But even then it is checked whether this is a real function.

Variant 1: Define a function, then use its name

```
function isNotEmpty($val){
  return !empty($val);
}

$arr = [0,1,[],null,false,"a","",(object)[],-1];

$res = array_filter( $arr);
$res1 = array_filter( $arr, 'isNotEmpty');
    
var_dump($res === $res1); //bool(true)
```

Variant 2: Use the [boolval](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.boolval.php) function

```
$arr = [0,1,[],null,false,"a","",(object)[],-1];

$res = array_filter( $arr);
$res1 = array_filter( $arr, 'boolval');

var_dump($res === $res1);  //bool(true)
```

With the function boolvar () this also works apparently. However, the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php) says:

> var The **scalar** value being converted to a bool.

But the examples for the boolval function also show an empty array as a value.

Comment: Variant 2 is what I was searching for. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any link to the article about remark? I can't find it out