# get specific array in a multi-dimentional array on php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following structure of an array which is decoded from a JSON object. From this array result I need to fork `widgets` for processing. It is an unstable JSON array so the parent keys may differs in future but the `widgets` will not.

```
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [MA] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [activities] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [activity_id] => 3
                                            [activity_name] => Excavation
                                            [activity_unique_id] => EXCAV-d435
                                            [created_date] => 2021-02-08 21:42:53
                                            [end_date] => 2021-02-08 21:42:08
                                            [fk_client_id] => 1
                                            [fk_main_activity] => 3
                                            [fk_project_id] => 2
                                            [relation_type] => MA-A-SA-W
                                            [start_date] => 2021-02-08 21:42:08
                                            [widgets] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [activity_mapping] => STRUC-be4c
                                                            [check_box_val] => 0
                                                            [checkbox_unique_id] => EXCAV-dceae
                                                            [checkbox_widget_id] => 5
                                                            [created_date] => 2021-02-08 21:43:12
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [created_date] => 2021-02-08 21:42:44
                            [end_date] => 2021-02-08 21:42:08
                            [fk_client_id] => 1
                            [fk_floor_ids] => 7
                            [fk_project_id] => 2
                            [main_activity_id] => 3
                            [main_activity_name] => Structure MA1
                            [main_activity_unique_id] => STRUC-be4c
                            [relation_type] => MA-A-SA-W
                            [sequence_no] => 1
                            [start_date] => 2021-02-08 21:42:08
                            [tower_ids] => 4
                            [widgets_ids] => 
                        )
```

...

it is a big source So I cut shorted it. From the above result set I only need to fork the following *widgets* object.

```
[widgets] => Array
      (
           [0] => Array
           (                   
             [activity_mapping] => STRUC-be4c
             [check_box_val] => 0
             [checkbox_unique_id] => EXCAV-dceae
             [checkbox_widget_id] => 5
             [created_date] => 2021-02-08 21:43:12
             )

         )

    )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: given your array structure is not stable, suggest you use a recursive function to filter for the 'widgets' key and return its contents. What have you tried?

Comment: @berend can you give any example for that. Do you mean iterating through the array like for loop inside for loop.?

Comment: You loop through it as $key => $value and check if key is widget, if not send $value to same function

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795671/4205384) should get you started.

Comment: _“Thanks in advance.”_ - please go read [ask]. This site is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @WKoppel I got your point. But since it has lot of parent nodes, the traditional foreach loop needs a lot of sub foreach to reach the widgets key right?. As I said the parent keys may change in future. I'm bit confused, It will be helpful if you can share any example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recursive function searches for the first occurrence of a key in a multidimensional array and returns its value.

```
function array_find_key(array $array, $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        return [$key => $array[$key]];
    } else {    
        foreach($array as $item) {
            if (is_array($item) && $result = array_find_key($item, $key)) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
}

$result = array_find_key($array, 'widgets');
```

[fiddle](https://3v4l.org/GdD9e)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @id'7238 is designed to search for a qualifying value in the current level before attempting to traverse a deeper level.  The nuance in my answer (which does not call `array_key_exists()`) is that it checks keys as it traverses a level and will go down a level as soon as a non-qualifying subarray is encountered.

While looping, if the key is found, the payload is returned (and potentially passed up the recursive stack).  If a value is array type data, then the next level down is processed -- if that level contains a qualifying key, it is passed up the stack.

If there are no qualifying keys in the input array, then `null` will be returned.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZsKJm))

```
function searchByKey(array $array, $find) {
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === $find) {
            return [$k => $v];
        }
        if (is_array($v)) {    
            $result = searchByKey($v, $find);
            if ($result) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_export(searchByKey($a, 'foo'));
```

Answer (score -1):

For fun, if the nesting level will be the same just with the keys being different, this will give you the `widgets` array:

```
$result = current(current(current(current(current($array)))))['widgets'];
```

This will give you the array under the `widgets` array:

```
$result = current(current(current(current(current(current($array)))))['widgets']);
```

The first example will only work if the `widgets` array is 5 levels deep in the array and for the second if there is only 1 array under widgets (if there are more you will get the first).